# When switching sites after executing a query that uses a user ID, it should not be carried over

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

When you execute [a query that uses your user ID](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/60998/display-user), it is prefilled automatically if you are logged into the Data Explorer.

If, after executing (because before that it isn't really possible for some reason), you select a different site's icon, the user ID is carried over. This happens with all other parameters within a parameterized query, too.

The only problem is: Now, it's wrong. While carrying over other parameters for convenience makes sense, the user with the same ID will be a completely different one between different sites. In fact, it's a bit annoying when trying to do ego-queries on several of your accounts, because you have to keep removing the UserId parameter from the URL to get it prefilled.

(The only exception where user IDs match is between a given site and its meta site, barring MSO.)

Comment: Hmm...good point. Will think what the best thing to do in this case might be.

Comment: @TimStone Not passing the UserId parameter in the URL, probably, unless switching between a site and its meta. Or you could automatically translate it so that it matches the same user account, but I don't know if that'd be feasible.

Comment: duplicate here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127896/dont-transfer-the-userid-when-changing-site-in-data-explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in the long term it'd be nice if Data Explorer mapped the user ID across sites where applicable by integrating with the API, but figuring out the best way to do that will take some more work.

For the time being though, I opted to follow your suggestion and [removed the UserID parameter](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=9199c4476a76045f4024137b2aa67cade38371f1) from the site-switching links except in the case of a non-SO meta/child switch.