# Don't transfer the UserId when changing site in Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [When switching sites after executing a query that uses a user ID, it should not be carried over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121483/when-switching-sites-after-executing-a-query-that-uses-a-user-id-it-should-not)

Normally, users have different UserId among different SE sites (don't understand why; I build a similar concept of sites and the accounts are shared with ids; but it doesn't matter anyway...). But the Data Explorer by default asumes the UserIds are the same.

Testcase:

1. Go to https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/947/my-comment-score-distribution. The UserId is filled automatically for you. So far so good.
2. Click "Run query".
3. Click icon of another SE site to select it.

**Now here's the problem:** the UserId at the current SE site is transfered to the URL! But because your UserId at the newly selected site is different, you have to manually remove it from the URL and reload the page again. Then, with no UserId in URL, the UserId is set automatically (and correctly).

**Just don't transfer the UserId to URL when clicking the SE site icon and that's it!**

Note: I was wondering if there is some more general concept of query parameters behind that `##UserId##`, in which case the transfering these general parameters to query another SE site would be perfectly OK. However, even in that case, the `##UserId##` parameter is recognized as specific anyway, because it is filled automatically by Data Explorer. So once it is specific this way, it can be also specific in that it is not transfered to the URL :-)

Comment: (Side note: this is one of the things on my to-do list for this week)

Comment: Sorry @Tim! I feel with you; I'm also developer and I hate if people ask me to do what I'm just about to do :-)

Comment: Ah, nothing to be sorry about, just letting you know it's forthcoming.  :)