# Error when attempting to download a .CSV file from SEDE

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

On the Stack Exchange Data Explorer site, when I try to request a `.CSV` file for the query I've just made, I get the ASP.NET error "regurgitation" (I don't know that there's anything meaningful in the text, but I'll include it anyway):

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons).
>   It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server
>   machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within
>   a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This  tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".

I get this in both Chrome and Firefox.  I have tried it with 3 possible sites (SO, MSO, and SU) and 2 different queries.

Comment: Did both queries have parameters? Looks like the URL isn't being updated properly in that case (which will result in an error). Looking into it now...

Comment: @TimStone No additional parameters.  I just ran http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/8009/distribution-of-user-activity-per-hour and http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/33647/generalist-badge which only take UserID as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121483/when-switching-sites-after-executing-a-query-that-uses-a-user-id-it-should-not), we were stripping out the `UserId` parameter from the query string being passed to the link templates. This worked well for using the site-switching links, but less so for links that were referencing the results of what you just executed and needed the full set of parameters (like the CSV and query plan download ones).

I made sure those links [get the parameters they need](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=b6bd1ea1177f3a4dd9173f7160c3a275884b696e) now and added a check in the CSV and query plan download routes to return a 400 Bad Request in the event that some of them are missing so we fail with something slightly more meaningful than the exception catch page.

The fix will hopefully go out in the near future, pending review. If you want, you can manually add the `?UserId=##` to the end of the CSV download link in the meantime and it should be available for download.