# The Download CSV link seems broken in SEDE query result window

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I've created [this query with a UserId parameter](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202355/csvlinks?UserId=187606)  which works nice. I would really like to download those results as an CSV file.

Therefor I click on the provided link on the right hand side of the screen called *Download CSV*.

The result is:

> The webpage cannot be found

<sup>https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/csv/202355?UserId=187606</sup>

I expected: A file in CSV format.

It looks like a regression of [this bug from 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141484/158100)

Queries without a parameter work as advertised.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Huh. It's not exactly a *regression*, but still weird. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was two-fold, and [both issues have been fixed](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/49) pending a pull and redeploy.

For cached results, the site value in the URL wasn't updated to use the right value, and that would result in a redirect (issue 1).

The redirect didn't bother to include the query string, so redirected requests with required query string parameters would end up failing with that bad request page (issue 2).

Comment: Thanks! 6-8 hours for the pull and redeploy? At the moment SEDE is at rev 2014.5.23.26....

Comment: Can't make promises about things not in my control. :P

Comment: We keep it on 6-8 units then...

Answer (score 2):

Since this bug keeps biting occasionally, I'll record a workaround here.

If a query has URL parameters, and you want to download its results:

1. Run the query
2. Delete parameters from the URL (`?` and everything after it)
3. Click *Run Query* again.
4. Click *Download CSV*

Source: [senshin](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18842/where-do-the-many-voters-in-the-2014-community-moderator-election-come-from/18965?noredirect=1#comment69047_18965)

Comment: Yes, the fix *still* hasn't been deployed. :( Think it's at least been merged though.