# Permanent (previous) data dump from a query?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I use a url like this: https://data.stackexchange.com/site/csv/qId?UserId=id to pull up a csv file from SEDE, but every week it doesn't pull up the csv unless I run the query. Running the query takes about 2 minutes every new week I run it. Is it possible to have a url to the csv that already exists, or is it deleted until the query is run again [every new week]?

Comment: You are logged-in on SEDE?

Comment: @rene Yes, go to an unpopular query and run it. You can test on that.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe it is related with this issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234239/the-download-csv-link-seems-broken-in-sede-query-result-window

Comment: While this isn't strictly supported, it should work in this case. What happens when it doesn't?

Comment: @TimStone two years later I will tell you it becomes a broken url, but ima close this as a dup of Rene's question